# Why the stored procedure needs an alphabet as suffix?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored Procedure as:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spGetEmployeesNotInSkill]
AS
BEGIN
SELECT COUNT (*) as Total FROM
(
   SELECT tblUser.EmployeeID FROM tblUser where tblUser.FirstName <> 'guest'
   EXCEPT
   SELECT tblSkillMetrics.EmployeeID FROM tblSkillMetrics
) r -- why is 'r' used here?
END
```

What I want to know is why are we using this `r`? If we change the `r` to any other letter "a/b/c/...x/y/z" it gives correct output, but if we remove it shows error.
Can anyone please explain this to me?

Comment: `r` is alias for subquery in round brackets, which is required in this case, it can be `r` or `t` or `myData` or any other valid identifier

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever you introduce a subquery, CTE, or anything else the will be providing rows as part of a query, you need to provide a name by which that particular set of rows may be referred to elsewhere in the query.

In the case of a table or view, the introduction of an alias is optional, and if omitted, the name of the table or view is used. But for anything else, the name must be explicitly provided.

E.g. you could have had:

```
SELECT COUNT (*) as Total FROM (
SELECT tblUser.EmployeeID FROM tblUser u where u.FirstName <> 'guest'
EXCEPT
SELECT tblSkillMetrics.EmployeeID FROM tblSkillMetrics)r
```

Where I've now introduced an alias(`u`) for `tblUser` in the inner query. And so in your query, `r` is the name/alias that's being used for the subquery as a whole.

Answer (score 1):

The `r` is being used as a table alias. The query is saying "select the number of records in this table that I'm going to call `r`". So you can call it anything you like.

When you select from a virtual table like this you have to give it an alias - it might be more helpful to call it something like `SkilledUsers` but as it's only used in one place it's quite common only to use a single character.

Answer (score 1):

It's a quirk of the SQL Server implementation of SQL.   The "r" is an alias for the subquery:  SQL Server requires that it must be named, even if it is not otherwise referenced.  You could just as easily have named it FOO or SUBQUERY or EMPLOYEES.

Other implementations of SQL don't impose this syntactic restriction.

Answer (score 1):

We are using `r` as an table alias.When u use `select * from (select cn from table_name) r` you are assigning name `r` to `derived` table `(select cn from table_name)`.It will be useful when you are using joins.